# Read a tab delimited txt file and write to separate column csv

Tags: python, csv

I have a txt file that have several lines for the headers which are represented by a '#'.

Then I have three columns each with their own header that I want to copy into a csv file that will allow for each column to have their own column in the spreadsheet.

Currently all I am able to get is a file that has all three columns in one section of the csv.

```
import csv

infile = r'path\seawater_nh.txt'
outfile = r'path\emissivity_new.csv'

print "definitions successful"

in_txt = csv.reader(open(infile, 'rb'), delimiter = '\t')
out_csv = csv.writer(open(outfile, 'wb'))

out_csv.writerows(in_txt)
```

Comment: Can you show the sample file?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your description of the problem, could you please post also a sample of the intended output?  If you want to add info to your post, click "edit" below the post text.

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of your sample input and output files, I'm guessing here.  But perhaps change how your files are read and written to (note: depending on the OS, you may need to change how the lines are read).

```
import csv

infile = r'path\seawater_nh.txt'
outfile = r'path\emissivity_new.csv'

with open(infile, "r") as in_text:
    in_reader = csv.reader(infile , delimiter = '\t')
    with open(outfile, "w") as out_csv:
        out_writer = csv.writer(out_csv, newline='')
        for row in in_reader:
            out_writer.writerow(row)
```